# "move_uploaded_file" uploads multiple files from local drive, but only single files from usb attached camera

Tags: php, file, move

From a usb attached camera (android phone), I can only upload a single file. I copied the folder from the camera to the local computer, and I can upload multiple files. the directory string is less than 250 characters. Is it a tmp file location issue?

input form:

```
<form action="result.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="upload_images[]" id="image_file" multiple >
```

result page:

```
$uploaded_images = array();
foreach($_FILES['upload_images']['name'] as $key=>$val){
    $upload_dir = "uploads/";
    $upload_file = $upload_dir.$ticket_num.'_'.$_FILES['upload_images']['name'][$key];
    $filename = $ticket_num.'_'.$_FILES['upload_images']['name'][$key];
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload_images']['tmp_name'][$key],$upload_file)){
        $uploaded_images[] = $upload_file;
        $insert_sql = "INSERT INTO uploads(id, file_name, upload_time) VALUES('', '".$filename."', '".time()."')";
    }
}
```

Comment: What browser are you uploading from, and on what operating system?

Comment: My inclination is that this is a client-side restriction. Have you tried with a different browser/OS/machine?

Comment: it was chrome on an older xp machine. Just tried with chrome on a win 10 mahine and get "Cannot open multiple items from this location. Try selecting a single item instead." USB Phone storage (Camera) shows up as Z835 on explorer, not as a drive letter.

Comment: if selecting files from local hard drive, multiple selections are not a problem.